# Adding different CSS files to different pages in Orchard CMS?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Let's say we have two pages in Orchard CMS. The homepage and the About US page. I want to use a RoyalSlider on the homepage which has its own CSS file. How do I include it only on the homepage and not on the about us page?

In Orchard CMS I am using Contoso as the theme and I tried including the royalslider.css file on the `Layout.cshtml` using `Style.Include` but this will include the CSS file over all the pages in the website which is not a good practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use URL Alternates feature for that. It's described [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates), in the section *"URL and Widget Alternates"*.

After enabling the feature, copy the `Layout.cshtml` you found in your theme and rename it to `Layout-url-homepage.cshtml`. This one will only be used for rendering the homepage, so just add your `Style.Include` calls there and you're set.

Comment: @AniketSharma Glad I could help. And would be even better to see that nice green check mark next to the answer;)

Comment: For less overhead on updating two complex layout files, a simple Razor check for the homepage can also include your page specific .js or .css

`code`

@{

    if (Request.Path == "/")
    {
        Style.Include("flexslider.css");
        Script.Include("flexslider.js");
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try 2 things.

1. Use the Classy feature in Vandaley Industries module (http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Vandelay.Industries). Then you can add a script to any content type.
2. Create an alternate at the corresponding URL.

They are many other ways, as Orchard is SOOOO extensible. Try these two first. :)

Comment: I tried Vandelay Classy but it allows you to enter CSS Classes and not files. Also, you can enter script URLs of Jquery or javascript but not CSS files. I will try the alternates. Thanks :)