# Can I change theme(css) for Specific page in Orchard cms?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I want to change background body image for specific pages.

How can I do that..?? Is there any functionality in Orchard CMS, or I have to do it manually... any suggestions..??

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854474/adding-different-css-files-to-different-pages-in-orchard-cms. You can also try in the Layout.cshtml: `if(Request.RawUrl == "/SpecificPage"){ Style.Include("specific.css" }`

Comment: actually I have found a solution for this.. As you know I want to change body background image.. I have used a jquery and javascript solution.. I am getting page name as my css class. and using this class I am controlling my background.. Have a look at my Code below.. & Thanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using(Script.Foot()) {
<script type ="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () { 
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var count = url.match(new RegExp("/", 'g'));
    var urlsplit = url.split("/");
    var page_class = urlsplit[1];

    $('body').addClass(page_class);
});
//]]>
</script>
}
```